# "Unless" in implication

Tags: logic, predicate

While learning about implications in predicate logic I came across a conditional statement,

> **Statement P is true implies statement Q is true** is equivalent to **Statement Q is true unless statement P is not true**.

But it seems counter intuitive to me, probably because of the word **unless**.
Can anybody please explain it to me that how they are equivalent.

Comment: "unless" = "except possibly if"

Comment: Simple Boolean algebra.

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at a list of equivalent statements:

1. **Statement P is true implies statement Q is true.**
2. If statement P is true, then statement Q must also be true.
3. The only way statement Q can be *not* true is if statement P is also not true (otherwise, P would be true, and then Q would also be true).
4. Statement Q is true unless it is not, in which case statement P is also not true.
5. **Statement Q is true unless statement P is not true.**

(Getting from point 2 to point 3 is called *contraposition* or taking the *contrapositive* - [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition).)

Comment: It is a bit counter-intuitive but, in logic, "P is true implies Q is true" is equivalent to "P is false, or Q is true, or both". http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=p+implies+q

Thus the "unless" statement that denotes that the implication is false if P is true and Q is false at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

In speaking of [Material Implication (`P ⊃ Q`)](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf), *unless P* means 'If (Not `P`)'.
That is, `P` is a negative "*if* clause".
It already contains a logical negation (`￢`)

- *Statement Q is true **unless** statement P is not true*

really means

- *Statement Q is true **if** (statement P is **not** (not true))* `True(P) ⊃ ￢￢ True(Q)`
  (the `￢￢` double negation comes from *not true* and the negative in *unless*),

or, combining terms, and changing the syntactic order to match the traditional logical order,

- *If statement P is true, statement Q is true.*  `True(P) ⊃ True(Q)`